# Inner Product Spaces Inequality Question

Tags: inequality, inner-products, integral-transforms

Prove that for any natural number $n$ and real numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ we have the inequality $$\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right| \le\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx^2_k\right)^\dfrac{1}{2}$$

My first thought was using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but I am not sure if we can use only one variable in it and

(edit so the next part of the sentence is probably not relevant but I will keep it anyway) that wouldn't include the $\dfrac{1}{n}$ on the left hand side and $\dfrac{1}{2}$ on the right hand side.

The next thing I was looking at was the norm of x.  $$\|\textbf{x}\|=\sqrt{\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{x}}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^nx^2_k}$$
And
$$\|\textbf{x}\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|$$
But I don't see how that would work with the second one, if anyone could give me a nudge in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Some further restrictions are needed if I am not mistaken. Take $n = 1,x_{1} = 1/2$, then $LHS = 1/2$ while $RHS= \sqrt{1/8}<1/2$

Comment: Oh, I just realised I didn't read my question right, it is a 1/n on the right hand as well

Comment: If it is $1/n$ on the right as well, then you can use Cauchy-Schwartz with $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y=(1/n,\ldots,1/n)$.

Comment: You should post an answer @BernardPan, I can't think of much more to say about the problem.

Comment: Hi @AndréArmatowski, an answer is posted. You can check it if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx^2_k\right)^\dfrac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n1^2\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2}\geq\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2}=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right|.$$

Comment: How does the first equality hold? I don't see why 1/n gets pulled out of the radical and n is placed in it

Comment: @Raven $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}a}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot na}=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{na}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let ${\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and ${\bf y}=(1/n,\ldots,1/n)$. Use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality,
\begin{align*}
\lVert{\bf x}\rVert\lVert{\bf y}\rVert&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k^2}\right)^{1/2}\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k^2}\right)^{1/2} \\
&\geq|\langle{\bf x},{\bf y}\rangle|=\left\lvert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_k}\right\rvert. 
\end{align*}
This answer is essentially the same as Michael's, except using different notations in the intermediate steps.

Comment: I think you forgot the square root on the second equality :) Good answer!

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Oops. That's my mistake! Thanks for telling me this!